# Vagrant not allowing NatNetwork on adapter 1

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Vagrant is forcing network type `nat` on adapter 1 (eth0) even when I have the network set as `natnetwork` in Virutalbox.
I can set up everything through Virtualbox manually and all my VMs can communicate with each other via eth0 as desired and port forwarding works as well.  I would like to get Vagrant to work the same way for easy distribution among coworkers.

It looks like others have this problem and it's not being addressed by Vagrant:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2779

Anyone know of a workaround?

**Details:**

```
$ VBoxManage list natnetworks
NetworkName:    ff_mgmt
IP:             10.0.2.1
Network:        10.0.2.0/24
IPv6 Enabled:   No
IPv6 Prefix:    fd17:625c:f037:2::/64
DHCP Enabled:   No
Enabled:        Yes
Port-forwarding (ipv4)
    https1:tcp:[]:4441:[10.0.2.11]:443
    https2:tcp:[]:4442:[10.0.2.12]:443
    https3:tcp:[]:4443:[10.0.2.13]:443
    ssh1:tcp:[]:2221:[10.0.2.11]:22
    ssh2:tcp:[]:2222:[10.0.2.12]:22
    ssh3:tcp:[]:2223:[10.0.2.13]:22
loopback mappings (ipv4)
    127.0.0.1=2
```

Relevant part of `Vagrantfile`:

```
boxes = [
{
    :name => "ff1",
    :ip => "10.0.2.11",
    :ssh_port => "2221",
    :https_port => "4441",
    :mac =>  "0800270fa302",
    :memory => "8192",
    :cpus => "4"
},
{
    :name => "ff2",
    :ip => "10.0.2.12",
    :ssh_port => "2222",
    :https_port => "4442",
    :mac =>  "0800270fb302",
    :memory => "8192",
    :cpus => "4"
},
{
    :name => "ff3",
    :ip => "10.0.2.13",
    :ssh_port => "2223",
    :https_port => "4443",
    :mac =>  "0800270fc302",
    :intnet2 => "seg5a",
    :memory => "8192",
    :cpus => "4"
}
]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
boxes.each do |opts|
    config.vm.define opts[:name] do |config|

        config.vm.box = "ff"
        #config.vm.box_version = 402

        config.vm.hostname = opts[:name]

        config.ssh.username = 'niska'
        config.ssh.private_key_path = '/home/niska/.ssh/id_rsa'
        config.vm.network :private_network, ip: opts[:ip]
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, guest_ip: opts[:ip], host: opts[:ssh_port], id: 'ssh'
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: opts[:https_port]

        config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.gui = false
            vb.memory = opts[:memory]
            vb.cpus = opts[:cpus]

            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nic1", "natnetwork"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--macaddress1", opts[:mac]]
            #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--intnet1", "ff_mgmt"]

        end
    end
end
```

Output of `vagrant up`.  Notice override of `natnetwork`. Also port forwarding picks different ports and therefore fails to connect.

```
$ vagrant reload ff1
==> ff1: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    ff1: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    ff1: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    ff1: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    ff1: capable.
==> ff1: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> ff1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> ff1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
->>>     ff1: Adapter 1: nat                       <<<--- (overrode w/ 'nat')
    ff1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> ff1: Forwarding ports...
    ff1: 22 (guest) => 2221 (host) (adapter 1)
    ff1: 443 (guest) => 4441 (host) (adapter 1)
==> ff1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> ff1: Booting VM...
==> ff1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    ff1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:22
    ff1: SSH username: niska
    ff1: SSH auth method: private key
    ff1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    ...
    Vagrant never connects
```

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html states that nic1 *must* be a NAT adapter. I'm unfamiliar with the difference between `natnetwork` and `nat` in VirtualBox, except that I know the former is the new one. Maybe Vagrant is unaware of the difference as well?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set nic1 (eth0) to anything other than NAT. virtualbox requires the first interface to be NAT.

```
ff1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

if you change the network type of the nic to natnetwork, then vagrant can't figure out how to ssh to the machine.

if you need vagrant at first to provision, change your network settings after you finish provisioning. however; after that point, you won't be able to use vagrant.

Comment: I was hoping for a workaround, not "don't do that"  :)  I ended up switching to vmware and vagrant, those two products together can solve this problem